# Apply function to specific columns of data frames in a list

Tags: r, list

I am working with a large list in R. Each element has 37 columns and more than 100 rows. I am trying to create a new list with the same dimensions but for specific columns I want to calculate a new value using the equation x*0.6/0.02587.

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do

```
my_list
$data1
X  Y  Z
1  2  3
2  4  2
3  5  7

new_list
$data1
X   Y   Z
1  60   90
2  120  60
3  150  210
```

I tried:

1. ```
   out<-lapply(data, FUN = function(x)(x*0.6)/0.02)
   ```

But this code applied the function to all columns of all elements in the list.

2. ```
   fun=function(x) {x = x*0.6/0.02587}

   out <- lapply(data , function(x) {x <- fun(x[c(2:37)]);
      x})
   ```

the code 2 did work too but in my new list only has 36 columns each element, it did drop the first column (the column I don't want to change).

Any help how to do that is very much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the data to the same columns back. Try -

```
fun=function(x) {x*0.6/0.02587}

out <- lapply(data , function(x) {x[2:37] <- fun(x[2:37]);x})
out
```